# Smartgwt : localfiltering on a selectItem

Tags: client, filtering, smartgwt

I have a Rpc Datasource providing a list of objects.  I have two `selectItem` databound to this datasource but each showing a different attribute.

For one of these attributes I have a duplicate value which are enabled by design.

However in the `SelectItem` related to this field I would like to remove duplicate to simplify the user choice(reduce the list length and also it seems strange to have double values..)

I think I can arrived to do it using lodal filtering but I cannot find the point to start to write the right citeria.